# Determining the complexities of the following functions (Big O)

Tags: c, big-o

I need help figuring out the complexities of these functions. In my opinion, the big o for these functions would be  O(2^n), O(n) and O(1) but I'm not sure so I would appreciate any help that I can get.

```
int func1(int n, int a, int b){
      
      int res=0;
    
      if (n == 1){
         res=a;
      }
    
      else{
        res=res+func1(n-1,a,b)+b;
      } 
    
      return res;
}


int func2(int n, int a, int b){
    
    int res = a;
    
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        res+=b;
    }
    
    return res;
}


int func3(int n, int a, int b){
    
    int res = a + (n-1)*b;
    return res;
    
}
```

Comment: I agree with the second and third one, but how do you come up with O(2^n) for the first one?

Comment: You're correct on the last two but wrong on the first.

Comment: For the first function: if n is 10 in the first call, how many times will `func1` be called? if n is 20 in the first call, how many times will `func1` be called? if n is 100 in the first call, how many times will `func1` be called?

Comment: what should the first one be then? I am not good with big o for recursion.

Comment: so the function is called n-1 times, i.e for n=10 it would be called 9 times in the recursion, for n=20 it would be 19. the base case is func1(1,a,b) = a.

Comment: @IshaanBedi So if 10 result in 9 calls, 20 result in 19 calls and 100 result 99 calls ans so on. And given there is no loops in the function - how does it scale. Does it scale like `n` itself? Does it scale like `n^2` ?

Comment: 20 results in 19 calls, 100 results in 99; this is a clear relation of (n-1) calls, which is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about #2 and #3.

For #1, you can take a look on it a bit differently. Your code can be refactored into:

```
int func1(int n, int a, int b){   
      if (n == 1){
         return 0;
      }
      return func1(n-1, a, b) + b;    
}
```

This is a clear and obvious case of [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), which [can straight forward be transferred to a loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Relation_to_while_construct) (and is often does by compilers):

```
int func1(int n, int a, int b){   
      int res = 0;
      while (n != 1) {
        n = n-1;
        res += b;
      }
      return 0 + res;
}
```

Now, this is quite to see that this is `O(n)`, and is very similar to your #2.